# IBM MQ fail with reason '2278' ('MQRC_CLIENT_CONN_ERROR')

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I have been trying with no luck to get a java app to connect to IBM MQ v8 via CCDT file.  I can connect fine when connecting using properties (hostname, port, etc) but with CCDT I consistently get **`WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2278' ('MQRC_CLIENT_CONN_ERROR').`**

I am using a vanilla install of MQ Developer 8.0 (version required, can't change) and the Jars from the installation.  All I did was install MQ, then setup a QueueManager 'QM1', then create a queue 'Q1'.

My code:

```
    package mqtest;

    import com.ibm.mq.jms.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
            File file = new File("C:/ProgramData/IBM/MQ/qmgrs/QM1/@ipcc/AMQCLCHL.TAB");
            URL clientChannelTableUrl = file.toURI().toURL();

            cf.setQueueManager("QM1");
            cf.setCCDTURL(clientChannelTableUrl);

            MQQueueConnection mqQueueConnection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**dis qmgr**

```
AMQ8408: Display Queue Manager details.
   QMNAME(QM1)                             ACCTCONO(DISABLED)
   ACCTINT(1800)                           ACCTMQI(OFF)
   ACCTQ(OFF)                              ACTIVREC(MSG)
   ACTVCONO(DISABLED)                      ACTVTRC(OFF)
   ALTDATE(2018-05-23)                     ALTTIME(10.21.26)
   AUTHOREV(DISABLED)                      CCSID(437)
   CERTLABL(ibmwebspheremqqm1)             CERTVPOL(ANY)
   CHAD(DISABLED)                          CHADEV(DISABLED)
   CHADEXIT( )                             CHLEV(DISABLED)
   CHLAUTH(ENABLED)                        CLWLDATA( )
   CLWLEXIT( )                             CLWLLEN(100)
   CLWLMRUC(999999999)                     CLWLUSEQ(LOCAL)
   CMDEV(DISABLED)                         CMDLEVEL(800)
   COMMANDQ(SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE)    CONFIGEV(DISABLED)
   CONNAUTH(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
   CRDATE(2018-05-23)                      CRTIME(10.21.26)
   CUSTOM( )                               DEADQ( )
   DEFCLXQ(SCTQ)                           DEFXMITQ( )
   DESCR( )                                DISTL(YES)
   INHIBTEV(DISABLED)                      IPADDRV(IPV4)
   LOCALEV(DISABLED)                       LOGGEREV(DISABLED)
   MARKINT(5000)                           MAXHANDS(256)
   MAXMSGL(4194304)                        MAXPROPL(NOLIMIT)
   MAXPRTY(9)                              MAXUMSGS(10000)
   MONACLS(QMGR)                           MONCHL(OFF)
   MONQ(OFF)                               PARENT( )
   PERFMEV(DISABLED)                       PLATFORM(WINDOWSNT)
   PSMODE(ENABLED)                         PSCLUS(ENABLED)
   PSNPMSG(DISCARD)                        PSNPRES(NORMAL)
   PSRTYCNT(5)                             PSSYNCPT(IFPER)
   QMID(QM1_2018-05-23_10.21.26)           REMOTEEV(DISABLED)
   REPOS( )                                REPOSNL( )
   REVDNS(ENABLED)                         ROUTEREC(MSG)
   SCHINIT(QMGR)                           SCMDSERV(QMGR)
   SPLCAP(ENABLED)                         SSLCRLNL( )
   SSLCRYP( )                              SSLEV(DISABLED)
   SSLFIPS(NO)
   SSLKEYR(C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key)
   SSLRKEYC(0)                             STATACLS(QMGR)
   STATCHL(OFF)                            STATINT(1800)
```

The error log in C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\errors has no relevant (that I can see at least) data in it.

As far as I can tell from various SO, IBM, Google searches this **should** work. As far as I can tell it has something to do with Channel definition or settings, but I just don't know what.

And, honestly, I think I have spent enough brain cells on this that I am most likely overlooking something important but can't see the small simple detail I am overlooking.  Any help as appreciated.

Comment: Did you search the web for `MQCC_FAILED 2278 MQRC_CLIENT_CONN_ERROR`? Did any of the _many_ hits address your question?

Comment: From the first hit: [***It also occurs in Java™ applications when a client channel definition table (CCDT) is specified to determine the name of the channel, but the table itself cannot be found.***](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q043080_.htm).  Does `C:/ProgramData/IBM/MQ/qmgrs/QM1/@ipcc/AMQCLCHL.TAB` exist?  Are its contents valid?

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison . I have searched, but as I mentioned I am probably overlooking something simple due to getting info overload.  To answer your other questions, the file exists, but as to whether it is valid I can't say as it is a binary file and I am unaware of any way to view the contents,. Thx

Comment: Did you define a `CLNTCONN` channel?    The file under the @ipcc is the default location that a MQ queue manager will put channels defined with type `CLNTCONN`, but default it would only include the `SYSTEM.DEF.CLNTCONN` channel.  When you define one you would need to use the same name as the `SVRCONN` channel you defined, you need to include `CONNAME('host(port)'` and `QMNAME(QM1)`.  You say it works when specifying properties, which channel name are you specifying?

Comment: Mike did you get this working?  If you can answer the questions from my earlier comment I'll take that and write up a answer or point you to some existing answers.  Highlevel steps: 1. define `SVRCONN`, 2. use `runmqsc -n` to define matching `CLNTCONN`.  Depending on the user connecting you may need to do some more work related to security (`CHLAUTH`, `CONNAUTH`, `OAM`).

Answer (score 0):

MQ Version: 9.0.0.4

Step 1: only one jar required: com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.0.4.0.jar

Step 2:
Do not set any variable in MQEnvironment

Step 3:

```
java.net.URL chanTab1 = new URL("file:///C:/MGR.TAB");          
MQQueueManager _queueManager = new MQQueueManager("*", chanTab1);
int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
MQQueue queue = _queueManager.accessQueue( "QNAME", openOptions,null,null, null );
```

MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();

`*` will allow you to connect all the QManager available in the .TAB file.

Step 4: 
Install certificate in your jre `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7\jre\bin` by command

```
keytool -import -alias example -keystore  ..\lib\security\cacerts -file C:\test.cer
```

default password is changeit. Mostly nobody change this. :-)

or

if you deployed your code on websphere application server then no need to install certificate in server JRE. Insted install certificate on Websphere server 
SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates > NodeDefaultKeyStore > Signer certificates > Retrieve from port

Comment: In the question the OP said they use MQ v8.0 and can't change.

Comment: not sure, But may be it will work on MQ 8.0 as well.